# Fatal error: Call to a member function getObject() on a non-object in

Tags: php, database, phpmyadmin

i am developing an e-commerce website stuck at this place i have SOF post on this error but didn't help me much.Aim is to grant discount to client on  basis of coupon code entered.see any one can help me out in this.

```
<?php
/**
  * Consider and apply voucher codes
  * Types of voucher code
  * - = FIXED AMOUNT OFF
  * % = PERCENTAGE OFF
  * s = SET NEW SHIPPING COST
  * @param voucherCode String
  * @return void
  */
  if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
  $code=$_POST["code"];
  $coupon=new coupon();
  $coupon->Vouchers($code);
  }

  class coupon {

   function Vouchers( $voucherCode )
  {
    //The voucher code value is checked to ensure it is not empty 
    // (as per point 1)
    if( $voucherCode != '' )
    {
      // we need the date, to see if the voucher has expired
      $cts = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
      $voucherCode=$this->registry;
      $voucher_sql = "SELECT *, if('{$cts}' > expiry, 1, 0)
                        AS expired FROM code
                      WHERE code='{$voucherCode}' LIMIT 1";
                      $voucher_sql=$this->registry;
      $this->registry->getObject('code')->executeQuery( $voucher_sql );
      if( $this->registry->getObject('code')->numRows() == 0 )
      {
        $this->voucher_notice = 'Sorry, the voucher code you entered
            is invalid';
      }
      else
      {
        $voucher = $this->registry->getObject('code')->getRows();
        if( $voucher['active'] == 1 )
        {
          if( $voucher['expired'] == 1 )
          {
            $this->voucher_notice = 'Sorry, this voucher has 
                expired';
            return false;
          }
          else
          {
            // check to see there are some vouchers, and customer
            // has enough in their basket (points 3 and 4)
            if( $voucher['num_vouchers'] != 0 )
            {
              if( $this->cost >= $voucher['min_cost'] )
              {
                $this->discountCode = $voucherCode;
                $this->discountCodeId = $voucher['id'];
                // If the discount operation is a percentage, then
                // the discount value is applied to the basket cost
                // to calculate that percentage. This amount is then
                // deducted from the order cost, giving a "discount
                // value"% discount from the order.
                if( $voucher['operation'] == '%' )
                {
                  $this->cost = $this->
              cost - (($this->cost)/100)*$voucher['amount'];
                  $this->voucher_notice = 'A ' 
                      . $voucher['amount'] 
                      . '% discount has been applied to your order';
                  return true;
                  // If the discount operation is a subtraction, then 
                  // the discount amount from the discount code is 
                  // deducted from the order cost, and the order cost 
                  // is updated to reflect this.
                }
                elseif( $voucher['operation'] == '-' )
                {
                  $this->cost = 
                      $this->cost - $voucher['amount'];
                  $this->voucher_notice = 'A discount of &pound;'
                      . $voucher['amount'] 
                      . ' has been applied to your order';
                  return true;
                  // Finally, if the discount operation is set to s 
                  // then, we set the shipping cost to the discount 
                  // value. This could allow us to set free shipping,
                  // or just reduce shipping costs.
                }
                elseif( $voucher['operation'] == 's' )
                {
                  $this->shipping_cost = $voucher['amount'];
                  $this->voucher_notice = 'Your orders shipping cost
                      has been reduced to &pound;' 
                      . $voucher['amount'];
                  return true;
                }
              }
              else
              {
                $this->voucher_notice = 'Sorry, your order total is 
                    not enough for your order to qualify for this 
                    discount code';
                return false;
              }
            }
            else
            {
              $this->voucher_notice = 'Sorry, this was a limited
                  edition voucher code, there are no more instances
                  of that code left';
              return false;
            }
          }
        }
        else
        {
          $this->voucher_notice = 'Sorry, the vocuher code you
              entered is no longer active';
          return false;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  }
  ?>
```

now running this code i get 
Fatal error: Call to a member function getObject() on a non-object in

here is my html form

```
<form method="post" action="a.php">
    Enter The Coupon Code:<br />
    <input name="code[]" type="text" size="10" />
    <br />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
    </form>
```

Comment: What is the complete error message ? It is likely because you tried to call a method on a variable that is not a object; it is often because of a missed check and a null value.

Comment: Fatal error: Call to a member function getObject() on a non-object in C:\Web Project\xampp\htdocs\shop\a.php on line 32

Comment: Additionaly, you do not check that $voucher is an object, just that it is different than '', which is not really a good check. You could use is_object to enforce this check, or use !empty.

Comment: Either $this->registry or $this->registry->getObject fails to return a proper object. You should check the return of all these calls to know where it failed.

Comment: how can we check that can u help me in this...

Comment: var_dump(get_class($this->registry));  then a var_dump(get_class($this->registry->getObject('code'))); . If any of those two calls throws an error saying that the given argument is not an object, you'll have the culprit. You will then be able to investigate further on why the call did not return a valid object.

Comment: thank's Naeil ....for your suggestion i caught the culprit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the error is

```
$this->registry->getObject
```

Now nowhere do you show registry being injected so that is the problem. I am assuming you are using a framework and expect this class to be container aware, which it is not. So inject the registry, or instatiate it in the constructor.